# How to get type arguments class of generic method parameter?

Tags: java, generics

How to get the type argument of an argument passed to a method ?  For example I have

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>(); 

public class Datastore {

  public <T> void insert(List<T> tList) {
     // when I pass the previous list to this method I want to get Person.class ; 
  }
}
```

Comment: IMHO this question is NOT duplicate. Putting aside answers in referred question are informationally rich and very useful otherwise, this question is about generic parameter of *methods* (not class), which is generally less covered topic on SO. And of course, unlike for classes, there is no solution of problem in this case.

Answer (score 14):

Due to type erasure, the only way you can do it is if you pass the type as an argument to the method.

If you have access to the Datastore code and can modify you can try to do this:

```
public class Datastore {
    public T void insert(List<T> tList, Class<T> objectClass) {
    }
}
```

and then call it by doing

```
List<Person> pList = new ArrayList<Person>();
...
dataStore.insert(pList, Person.class);
```

Every response I've seen to this type of question was to send the class as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 4):

Due to Type Erasure I doubt whether we can get it, barring some reflection magic which might be able to do it.

But if there are elements inside the list, we can reach out to them and invoke getClass on them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that. Check out this class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NoSuchFieldException
     * @throws SecurityException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new TestClass().getClass().getDeclaredField("list").getGenericType(); // this is the type parameter passed to List
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new TestClass().<Integer> insert(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    public <T> void insert(List<T> tList)
    {
        ParameterizedType paramType;
        paramType = (ParameterizedType) tList.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];
        paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass();
    }
}
```

You can get the type parameters from a class or a field but it is not working for generic methods. Try using a non-generic method!

**OR**

another solution might be passing the actual `Class` object to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
if(tList != null && tList.size() > 0){
    Class c = tList.get(0).getClass();
}
```

Comment: For this to work there should be elements in the list, which is not there in question.

Comment: This is what It was before !

Comment: This requires non-empty array. Otherwise would work. May be suitable for specific case when no type information (say no work at all) is required for the empty array.