# Autocomplete in return type Typescript based on input object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Update:** thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5575595/drag13 completed version can be found here: https://github.com/web-ridge/react-ridge-translations/blob/main/src/index.ts

I'm working on a translation library for React / React Native but I can't get the types to work.

https://github.com/web-ridge/react-ridge-translations

You can create a translation in the following way

```
// first describe which languages are allowed/required (Typescript)
type TranslationLanguages = {
    nl: string
    fr: string
    en: string
}

// create a translation object with your translations
export default const translate = createTranslations<TranslationLanguages>({
  homeScreen:{
    yesText: {
      nl: 'Ja',
      fr: 'Oui',
      be: 'Yes',
    },
    welcomeText: ({ firstName }: { firstName: string }) => ({
      nl: `Hoi ${firstName}`,
      fr: `Hello ${firstName}`,
      be: `Hello ${firstName}`,
    }),
  }
}, {
    language: 'nl',
    fallback: 'en',
})
```

The library changes the object to the following

```js
{
  homeScreen:{
    yesText: 'Ja',
    welcomeText: ({ firstName }: { firstName: string }) => `Hoi ${firstName}`,
  }
}
```

In your component you will use the types in this way

```
  const {yesText,welcomeText} = translate.use().appScreen
```

It won't autocomplete the types.

Library code (simplified)

```
type val<T> = (...params: any[]) => T
type val1<T> = T

type Translations<T> = {
    [group: string]: {
        [key: string]:  val<T> | val1<T>
    },
}
type TranslationsObject<T> = {
    translations: Translations<string>,
    use: () => Translations<string>;
}
export function createTranslations<T>(t: Translations<T>): TranslationsObject<T>
```

How can I let Typescript understand that it needs to autocomplete?

Comment: Your first link returns 404 :(

Comment: Fixed now master branch was changed to main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to allow TypeScript to define interface himself. In this case, you need to use more generics. Something like this:

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]; 
type Translations<TGroup> = {
   [group in keyof TGroup]: { [key in keyof ValueOf<TGroup>]: ValueOf<TGroup>[key] }
}

type TranslationsObject<TGroup> = {
    translations: Translations<TGroup>,
    use: () => Translations<TGroup>;
}

export function createTranslations<TGroup>(data: TGroup): TranslationsObject<TGroup> { }


const test = createTranslations({
  homeScreen:{
    yesText: {
      nl: 'Ja',
      fr: 'Oui',
      be: 'Yes',
    },
    welcomeText: ({ firstName }: { firstName: string }) => ({
      nl: `Hoi ${firstName}`,
      fr: `Hello ${firstName}`,
      be: `Hello ${firstName}`,
    }),
  }
});

const x  = test.use().homeScreen.yesText
```

Type checking should work fine for now. Does this look good?

*Updated with code from comment*

Comment: I think I will get this working! Thanks a lot

I have one addition which made it fully working maybe edit the answer 
```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type Translations<TGroup, TValue> = {
    [group in keyof TGroup]: {
        [key in keyof ValueOf<TGroup>]:  val<TValue> | val1<TValue>
    }
}
```

Comment: @RichardLindhout Looks great! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Works almost perfect but it does not yet understand the welcomeText: ({ firstName }:

It said: Not all constituents of type 'string | val<string>' are callable.     Type 'string' has no call signatures.

I doubt it's possible to make that working based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953359/how-to-get-type-arguments-class-of-generic-method-parameter

Comment: Oh lol the link in my comment is Java and not Typescript xD

Comment: Don't you forget to change val to ValueOf?
```[group in keyof TGroup]: { [key in keyof ValueOf<TGroup>]: ValueOf<TValue> | ValueOf<TValue> }```
For me this works perfectly fine: 
```const test = createTranslations({ welcomeText: { firstName:'test' }});```

Comment: Than it gives me any

Comment: I now have this
type CopyFunction<TFn, TR> = TFn extends (...a: infer A) => any ? (...a:A) => TR: never
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type Translations<TGroup> = {
    [group in keyof TGroup]: {
        [key in keyof ValueOf<TGroup>]:  CopyFunction<ValueOf<TGroup>, string> | string
    }
}

Comment: Why can't stackoverflow make code snippets working here XD

Comment: It still gives me any

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217169/discussion-between-richard-lindhout-and-drag13).

Comment: I just released version 1 of the package. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is here

```js
type Translations<T> = {
    [group: string]: {
        [key: string]:  val<T> | val1<T>
    },
}
```

Because of the indexer declaration, TypeScript doesn't know anything about the inner structure. If you want to have more strong types, here is the option:

```js
type val<T> = (...params: any[]) => T
type val1<T> = T
type TransltionGroup = 'homeScreen' | 'personalCabinet';
type Translations<T> = {
    [group in TransltionGroup]: {
        [key: string]:  val<T> | val1<T>
    }
}
type TranslationsObject<T> = {
    translations: Translations<string>,
    use: () => Translations<string>;
}
export function createTranslations<T>(t: Translations<T>): TranslationsObject<T> { }

const test = createTranslations({ homeScreen: { test: '4' }, personalCabinet: { test: '6' } });

const x  = test.use().personalCabinet
```

And of course, you may declare the type for the subgroup

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks nice! But I would want the group automatically since I don't want to let my typescript users define it by themselves

Comment: In this case (if I understand you correctly) it looks like you need one more generic. If you don't mind I will one more answer, because the question is a bit different

Comment: No problem I truly appreciate your help!